# How to display an image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, imshow

I tried to use IPython.display with the following code:

```
from IPython.display import display, Image
display(Image(filename='MyImage.png'))
```

I also tried to use matplotlib with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread('MyImage.png'))
```

In both cases, nothing is displayed, not even an error message.

Answer (score 376, accepted):

If you are using matplotlib and want to show the image in your interactive notebook, try the following:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
img = mpimg.imread('your_image.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it almost works :-) The image is displayed, but the gray levels are replaced using a fire lut. Any idea?

Comment: Try defining the colormap explicitly: plt.imshow(lum_img, cmap="grey")

Comment: In my understanding, the last plt.show() command produces the display. Before that, you could add to the plot, e.g. by adding layers to the image. I recommend the matplotlib image tutorial as a reference: http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers, now it works perfectly! Just a little details for the potential readers, it "gray" instead of "grey".

Comment: You could avoid using `matplotlib.image`: 
img = plt.imread('your_image.png')

Comment: @perfo he meant the argument 'gray' rather than how to spell the word. 

"""
cmaps['Sequential (2)'] = [
            'binary', 'gist_yarg', 'gist_gray', 'gray', 'bone', 'pink',
            'spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter', 'cool', 'Wistia',
            'hot', 'afmhot', 'gist_heat', 'copper']
"""

Comment: @Ari. I guess so.

Comment: If the image's resolution seems lower than the original, add this before the imread : `plt.figure(dpi=600)`. More detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39870642/matplotlib-how-to-plot-a-high-resolution-graph)

Answer (score 58):

In a much simpler way, you can do the same using

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('image.jpg')
image.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've installed PIL and now it works. Any idea why the two methods I tried didn't work?

Comment: If failing to install PIL (as was the case for me), try Pillow, it worked like a charm for me.

Comment: I wonder how the `import Image` statement works; shouldn't it be `from PIL import Image`?

Comment: This solution does not necessarily close the file descriptor. Instead, use it with a context manager:
`with Image.open('image.jpg') as im: im.show()`

Comment: What is this `Image` package?

Comment: Image is from old PIL package, now use `from PIL import Image`

Comment: Heads up, when using in an environment that doesn't have access to a browser (i.e., Kaggle, Colab, SageMaker, JupyterServer), I can't get this to work and receives the error "www-browser: not found".

Answer (score 56):

If you use `matplotlib`, you need to show the image using `plt.show()` unless you are not in interactive mode.
E.g.:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(sample_image) 
plt.show()  # display it
```

Comment: Reading an other answer, I just got that I have to add plt.show() after the code I already have, instead of replacing the imshow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this answers the question precisely as compared to the accepted answer.

Comment: You can get sample_image like: ```sample_image = plt.imread(file_path)```

Answer (score 13):

Your first suggestion works for me

```
from IPython.display import display, Image
display(Image(filename='path/to/image.jpg'))
```

Comment: This will always display first if there are also other plots, why is that?

Comment: not sure. I'm not an ipython expert. There are several ways to show an image as you can see from the answers here.

Comment: Image is not being displayed in ubuntu terminal, any other tab is not opened to display the image. Do you have any answer for this. But it's working on colab

Comment: This is the best answer!!

Answer (score 10):

Using opencv-python is faster for more operation on image:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
im_resized = cv2.resize(im, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(im_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simple 
Use following pseudo code

```
from pylab import imread,subplot,imshow,show

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = imread('...')  // choose image location

plt.imshow(image)
```

`plt.show()` // this will show you the image on console.

Answer (score 4):

Using Jupyter Notebook, the code can be as simple as the following.

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import Image
Image('your_image.png')
```

Sometimes you might would like to display a series of images in a for loop, in which case you might would like to combine `display` and `Image` to make it work.

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.display import display, Image
for your_image in your_images:
    display(Image('your_image'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
```

What it should be:

```
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread('MyImage.png'))
File_name = mpimg.imread('FilePath')
plt.imshow(FileName)
plt.show()
```

you're missing a `plt.show()` unless you're in Jupyter notebook, other IDE's do not automatically display plots so you have to use `plt.show()` each time you want to display a plot or made a change to an existing plot in follow up code.

Answer (score 2):

```
import IPython.display as display
from PIL import Image
image_path = 'my_image.jpg'
display.display(Image.open(image_path))
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Jupyter notebook PIL image visualization with arbitrary number of images:

```
def show(*imgs, **kwargs):
    '''Show in Jupyter notebook one or sequence of PIL images in a row. figsize - optional parameter, controlling size of the image.
    Examples:
    show(img)
    show(img1,img2,img3)
    show(img1,img2,figsize=[8,8])
    '''
    
    if 'figsize' not in kwargs:
        figsize = [9,9]
    else:
        figsize = kwargs['figsize']
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,len(imgs),figsize=figsize)
    if len(imgs)==1:
        ax=[ax]
    
    for num,img in enumerate(imgs):
        ax[num].imshow(img)
        ax[num].axis('off')
        
    tight_layout()
```

Comment: Kudos for the `ax.axis('off')`

Answer (score 0):

To display images in python, you can use a tool that I made.

1. Install python3:

   - apt install python3
2. Clone the repo:

   - git clone https://github.com/404rgr/print-image-in-terminal
3. Install python required libs:

   - cd print-image-in-terminal
   - pip3 install numpy
   - pip3 install pillow

Usage:
python3 print_image.py [path to image]

Examples:
python3 print_image.py sinchan.jpg