# viewing images from local path(directory) in python?

Tags: python

i'm trying to retrieve images from my local directory using array list but i got all images from list but i don't know how to show images from list one by one. 
Please help me if anyone knows.

my.py:

```
import os, os.path

imgs = []
# print(imgs)
path = "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/my_module/static/files"
valid_images = [".jpg",".gif",".png",".tga"]
print(valid_images)
for f in os.listdir(path):
    ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    os.listdir(path).append(f)
    # Image.show(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried and i got my expected output.
py:

```
  import os
    from PIL import Image
    img=[]
    path="C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/my_module/static/files/"
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
        os.listdir(path).append(f)
        image = Image.open(f)
        image.show()
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several options depending on your environment and visualization libraries. Check this good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286540/display-an-image-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `from PIL import Image`, then you could do `Image.open(path + "/" + f).show()`. Try this:

```
import os, os.path
from PIL import Image

imgs = []

path = "path/to/directory" 

valid_images = [".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".tga"]
print(valid_images)

for f in os.listdir(path):   
    ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    if ext in valid_images:
        imgs.append(path + "/" + f)
    img = Image.open(path + "/" + f)
    img.show()

print(imgs)
```

Comment: Sir., i want to fetch only one image based on the condition. for example if the count is 3 i want to fetch any one image from my local directory... i'm trying but i don't know how to fetch only one element.. can you help me  sir