# rpy2 and R-imager - how to write in Python?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to achieve these 4 lines of R-code in Python:

```
library(imager)
file <- system.file('extdata/parrots.png',package='imager')
im <- load.image(file)
plot(im)
```

Essentially, I want to be able to run all of these R-functions in Python: https://dahtah.github.io/imager/imager.html 
(the above code is the first example)

Thanks!

Comment: Is it your expectation to run this as R code, or do you just want calls to the R engine from Python?

Comment: Is there a reason why you prefer using the R code above and not the python matplotlib library?  The same results can be achieved with a similar amount of python code.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286540/display-an-image-with-python/35286615

Comment: My professor really prefers R.. that is really the main reason. 
Can matplotlib do anything that R can for visualizations? 

But for a compromise, I want to ensure her that if needed I can use R within Python.