# How to Save files as Original file name using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, opencv

Hi I want to save the predicted image in a folder using the same name as the original but my cv2.imwrite is not saving the images in the folder.

```
path2=r'/data/folder/'
def get_segmented(image):
    for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob(image)):
        
        print(file,i)
        start_time = time()
        image = image_loader(file)
    
        output = model(image)
        output = output.detach().cpu()
        output = np.resize(output, (160, 160))
        
        img_filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        print(cv2.imwrite(path2 + img_filename + '.png',output*255))
```

Comment: Why is there a print at the end? Have you tried avoiding print? I would try with just `cv2.imwrite(path2 + img_filename + '.png',output*255)`.

Comment: Just to see the output is saving or not

Comment: What is your problem, saving file with original name or saving file?

Comment: saving with the original name. when I run this code cv2.imwrite output is False

Comment: What you you providing in `image` argument? and why are you implementing loop for there? and also are you sure that your `output` is of `numpy.ndarray` class?

Comment: image=path of images

Comment: Try to visualize final output image using `matplotlib` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html https://stackoverflow.com/a/35287898/12446721

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have solved the issue, the output is numpy.ndarray class