# Show multiple PNG pictures from a list in python

Tags: python, png

I would like to show the first 5 pictures from a folder, consisting of .png pictures. How can I do that, without calling them one by one via their name in python?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display an image with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35286540/display-an-image-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package `os` to list file in a directory. Then you filter the results to keep the files with the correct extention. You take the 5 first elements of the list. Finaly you use `matplotlib.image` to load the image and `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot the image.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

filenames = os.listdir()
filenames = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.png'), filenames))
filenames = filenames[:5]

for f in filenames:
    plt.imshow(mpimg.imread(f))
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from PIL import Image


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("directory path"):
    for file in files:
        if file.lower().endswith(".png"):
           image = Image.open(os.path.join(subdir,file)
           image.show()
```

I think that should do it. May need to do `image.close()` after `image.show()`